# CSS: I set the sub-menu to be display:none, and hover will show display: block, but it does not work

Tags: html, css

I set the sub-menu to be `display: none`, and hover will show `display: block`, but it does not work.

For the following HTML hover `main-menu-link` to show the sub-menu:

```css
.main-menu-link:link,
.main-menu-link:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.main-menu-link:hover,
.main-menu-link:active {
  color: #e67e22;
}

.sub-menu {
  /* background-color: red; */
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  /* set  the sub menu to be none */
  display: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.main-menu-link:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul class="main-nav-list">
    <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#product">Product</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="main-menu-link" href="#">Facilities & processing</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a class="sub-menu-link" href="#facilities">Facilities</a>
          <li><a class="sub-menu-link" href="#processing">Processing </a></li>
      </ul>

      </li>
      <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#processing">Processing </a></li>
      <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#procurement-sales">Procurment & Sales</a></li>
```

Comment: You have added the hover statement on hover "a" but the "sub-menu" is the child of "li", not "a"

Answer (score 2):

Add Class to the `li` tag and then set the hover.

```css
.main-menu-link:link,
.main-menu-link:visited {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.main-menu-link:hover,
.main-menu-link:active {
  color: #e67e22;
}

.sub-menu {
  /* background-color: red; */
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 12%;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  /* set  the sub menu to be none */
  display: none;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .sub-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main-nav">
  <ul class="main-nav-list">
    <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#introduction">Introduction</a></li>
    <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#product">Product</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="main-menu-link" href="#">Facilities & processing</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a class="sub-menu-link" href="#facilities">Facilities</a>
          <li><a class="sub-menu-link" href="#processing">Processing </a></li>
      </ul>

      </li>
      <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#processing">Processing </a></li>
      <li><a class="main-nav-link" href="#procurement-sales">Procurment & Sales</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```